# What is causing this compilation error with g++?

Tags: networking, c++17

I am trying to use asio library for networking in c++ but I have failed to load it.
I am using visual studio code, mingw/g++
This is the path to my include folder -> C:\msys64\mingw64\include
Here is the code in my main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/internet.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
This is the result of compilation

C:\Users\2022\Desktop\TUTORIALS\C++\SocketsTutorial>g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I C:\Users\2022\Downloads\asio-1.24.0\asio-1.24.0\include
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\2022\AppData\Local\Temp\cc33Br48.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS1_4dataEhh[_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS1_4dataEhh]+0x74): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\2022\AppData\Local\Temp\cc33Br48.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS1_4dataE[_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS1_4dataE]+0x35): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You should add compilation command that generates the error. Also you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472772/12463055) for solution of similar question.

Comment: This is the command -> g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I C:\Users\2022\Downloads\asio-1.24.0\asio-1.24.0\include

Comment: You should add library called `ws2_32` for Windows socket. The final command should be `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I C:\Users\2022\Downloads\asio-1.24.0\asio-1.24.0\include -lws2_32`. I have never used that asio library but it should be work.

Comment: I love you bro you have saved my life